# Angularjs broadcast and on query

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angularJS broadcast and emit . The below code doesn't seem to work i.e the FirstCtrl and SecondCtrl are not receiving broadcast messages . Any

```
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">  </div>    
</div>

var app = angular.module("myapp", []);

function FirstCtrl($scope){
    this.name = "xxxx";
    this.age  = 31;

    $scope.$on("message", function(e, opt){
        console.log("received message First");
    });
}
function SecondCtrl($scope){
    this.name = "yyyy";
    this.age  = 31;
    $scope.$on("message", function(e, opt){
        console.log("received message second");
    });

}

app.controller("FirstCtrl", FirstCtrl);
app.controller("SecondCtrl", SecondCtrl);
app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on("message", function(e,opt){
        console.log("root receive message");
    });

    $rootScope.$broadcast("message", { message : "root broadcast"});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example illustrates an important point. Controllers are created and destroyed during the life cycle of an app. They can miss broadcast events. On the otherhand services are **singletons** and available for the entire lifetime of the app. So record your events in a service.

```
app.factory("messageService", function($rootScope) {
     var lastMessage = {};
     function getMessage() { return lastMessage };
     function setMessage(m) { lastMessage = m };
     //record events
     $rootScope.$on("message" function(e,opt) {
          lastMessage.event = e;
          lastMessage.opt = opt;
     });
     return { getMessage: getMessage,
              setMessage: setMessage
            };
});
```

Your controllers can then "catch-up" and subscribe to the events.

```
app.controller("FirstCtrl", function($scope,messageService) {
     //catch-up
     var message = messageService.getMessage();
     console.log(message.opt.message);
     //subscribe
     $scope.$on("message", function (e,opt) {
          message.event = e;
          message.opt = opt;
          console.log(message.opt.message);
     });
});
```

In your run block be sure to inject the `messageService`.

```
app.run(function($rootScope, messageService){
    $rootScope.$on("message", function(e,opt){
        console.log("root receive message");
    });

    $rootScope.$broadcast("message", { message : "root broadcast"});
});
```

The AngularJS framework does lazy instantiation of services. Even though the run block doesn't use the `messageService`, it needs to be instantiated to receive and record the broadcast events.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when the `run` block is executing, none of the controllers have been instantiated.

To resolve this, use a `$timeout` so that sufficient time is allowed for the controllers to be instantiated:

```
$timeout(function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast("message", { message : "root broadcast"});
}, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [`angular-PubSub`](https://github.com/georapbox/angular-PubSub) to avoid sending events to more than necessary controllers.

`$rootScope.$broadcast` will send event to all Scopes which may not be efficient in case you have lot of controllers/scopes. In this case, it is advised to use PubSub pattern efficiently.

**NOTE** Don't forget to unsubscribe events/topics to avoid memory leaks.